# How do I improve the precision of Vue Draggable nesting?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, draggable, vue.draggable

I have been working on a form builder using Vue 2 Components and the Vue.Draggable library. This works well, aside from one ongoing issue – nested blocks are very hard to actually nest, for the end user. It requires a lot of precision, and trial and error, to get a block to indent under another.

How can I resolve this issue and make it easier to use? It appears almost like it's because of the lack of a drop zone.

[image: The issue demonstrated] (link to Imgur as animated images cannot be embedded)

Please note that I was unable to run the code in CodePen due to the multiple file nature. The code also relies on TailwindCSS for the UI.

`/FormBuilder.vue`

```
<style>
    .wrapper {
        margin-bottom: -1rem;
    }
    .group.templates {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        margin: 0 -0.5em;
    }
    .group.templates .field {
        margin: 0 0.5rem;
    }
    .group.elements {
        margin-top: 1rem;
    }
    .group.elements .field {
        margin: 1rem 0;
    }
    .group.elements .field + div {
        margin-left: 1rem;
    }
    .group.elements .ghost {
        opacity: 0.5;
    }
</style>

<template>
    <div>
        <div>
            <draggable :list="templates" :group="{ name: 'form-builder', pull: 'clone', put: false }" :clone="cloneTemplate" :component-data="getComponentData()">
                <div v-for="element in templates" :key="element.name">
                    <div class="field bg-white rounded shadow rounded font-bold text-gray-700 px-4 py-2">
                        <h4 class="font-bold"><i class="fas mr-2" :class="[ 'fa-' + element.icon ]"></i> {{ element.name }}</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </draggable>
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <nested-draggable :items="elements" name="form-builder"></nested-draggable>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import Draggable from 'vuedraggable'
    import NestedDraggable from './FormBuilder/NestedDraggable'

    export default {
        components: {
            Draggable,
            NestedDraggable,
        },

        data() {
            return {
                id: 6,
                templates: [
                    {
                        name: 'Field',
                        icon: 'heading',
                        type: 'field'
                    }
                ],
                elements: [
                    {
                        id: 1,
                        type: 'test',
                        locked: true,
                        options: {
                            text: "field"
                        },
                        children: []
                    },
                    {
                        id: 2,
                        type: 'paragraph',
                        locked: false,
                        options: {
                            text: "field"
                        },
                        children: []
                    },
                    {
                        id: 3,
                        type: 'field',
                        locked: false,
                        options: {
                            text: "field"
                        },
                        children: [
                            {
                                id: 4,
                                type: 'field',
                                locked: false,
                                options: {
                                    text: "field"
                                },
                                children: []
                            },
                            {
                                id: 5,
                                type: 'field',
                                locked: false,
                                options: {
                                    text: "field"
                                },
                                children: []
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        },

        methods: {
            cloneTemplate(object) {
                return {
                    id: this.id++,
                    type: object.type,
                    locked: false,
                    options: {},
                    children: []
                }
            },
            getComponentData() {
                return {
                    attrs: {
                        class: 'group templates'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

`/FormBuilder/NestedDraggable.vue`

```
<template>
    <draggable ghost-class="ghost" :list="items" :group="name" :component-data="getComponentData()">
        <div v-for="element in items" :key="element.id">
            <field v-if="element.type == 'field'" :locked="element.locked" :options="element.options"></field>
            <nested-draggable v-if="element.children" :items="element.children" :name="name"></nested-draggable>
        </div>
    </draggable>
</template>

<script>
    import draggable from 'vuedraggable'

    import field from "./Fields/Field"

    export default {
        name: 'nested-draggable',

        components: {
            draggable,
            field
        },

        props: {
            name: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            },
            items: {
                type: Array,
                required: true
            }
        },

        methods: {
            getComponentData() {
                return {
                    attrs: {
                        class: 'group elements'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

`/FormBuilder/Fields/Field.vue`

```
<template>
    <div class="field bg-white rounded shadow rounded">
        <div class="px-4 py-2 border-b flex flex-row items-center text-gray-700">
            <h4 class="font-bold mr-4"><i class="fas fa-heading mr-2"></i> Field</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="p-4 pt-2">
            <label for="content" class="form-label">Content</label>
            <input type="text" id="content" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: {
            locked: {
                type: Boolean,
                default: false
            },
            options: {
                type: Object,
                default: () => {
                    return {
                        content: ''
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I was looking for this as well. Since this uses SortableJS as its base, sortable does have a threshold option called `swapThreshold`, however, I could not find this option referenced at all when searching the Vue-Draggable repository.

Sortable options: https://github.com/SortableJS/Sortable#options

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with the `options` prop. Vue Draggable uses SortableJS. Right now it still passes options through the `options` prop.

```
<template>
<draggable :options="{swapThreshold: 0.5}">
    <div v-for="element in items" :key="element.id">
        <field v-if="element.type == 'field'" :locked="element.locked" :options="element.options"></field>
        <nested-draggable v-if="element.children" :items="element.children" :name="name"></nested-draggable>
    </div>
</draggable>
```

In the example I show above, I am decreasing the threshold by half.

https://github.com/SortableJS/Sortable#swapthreshold-option

> swapThreshold option
>
> Percentage of the target that the swap zone will take up, as a float between 0 and 1.

#### Caution

The `option` prop is deprecated and will be removed in future versions. I assume its there as a fallback for the other options it has not yet implemented, like `swapThreshold`.

More details about the deprecated notice here:
https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable/blob/master/documentation/migrate.md#options-props

If there are other options you would like to use that aren't in the Vue Draggable docs, you can check out SortableJS's options page to see what you can still use:

https://github.com/SortableJS/Sortable#options

Answer (score 0):

For me the :emptyInsertThreshold='20' argument does real wonders. You have to fiddle with the value a little bit but it solved my nesting issues.